# Call JBOSS application from Tomcat Application

Tags: tomcat, redirect, jboss

I have an application running on Tomcat 6 server on port 8080 and I have separate applications running on JBOSS 7.4.0 on port 8180. I need to access the JBOSS application from tomcat sever by clicking on the UI on tomcat application. Please help  how to do this.

*What I've tried so far:*

I've Installed Apache and from there I modified the `httpd.conf` file using the `ProxyPass` attribute (port 8080 is tomcat and 8180 is jboss). So using this I'm able to redirect to tomcat but not on Jboss. Please help.

```
ProxyPass /olb/auth/  http://localhost:8080/olb/auth/

ProxyPassReverse /olb/auth/ http://localhost:8080/olb/auth/

ProxyPass /olb/balances/  http://localhost:8080/olb/balances/

ProxyPassReverse /olb/balances/ http://localhost:8080/olb/balances/

ProxyPass /olb/collections/  http://localhost:8180/olb/collections/

ProxyPassReverse /olb/collections/ http://localhost:8180/olb/collections/
```

Comment: You need to do some research, make an attempt at this, post what you tried and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Comment: I have posted what I tried.Thanks